# What's the best wordpress cache plugin for a moderately trafficked server?

Tags: wordpress, cache

I'm supporting a moderately trafficked Wordpress server, with 2GB ram and a dual-core amd opteron CPU, running Gentoo. It looks like it's just a default install, so I'll be tuning mysql, but I'm also planning on dropping in one of the various caching plugins for wordpress.

Which plugins should I consider for this? Are there any significant differences between them that I should take into account while selecting them?

[This article on coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001105.html) suggests WP-Cache, WP-Super-Cache, or Bad Behavior - are there other plugins out there to include in my quick survey?

Comment: I suggest you check out the Wordpress forums, where such things are no doubt discussed constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally used WP-Super-Cache when one of my Wordpress installations was being slammed. I'd recommend giving them a try depending on your needs. I'm one of those strange people who likes optimizing and caching all but the most critical of pages (yet still appear dynamic).

Answer (score 3):

I realize this post is rather old but maybe someone else will benefit.

I used WP Super Cache until I found this one:

W3 Total Cache - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/